# Scala Map Save to File - Hadoop

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hdfs

**Scala is being used with hadoop**

I have performed map-reduce on a text file stored in hdfs (hadoop). The file is large, therefore, I have attempted to extract the important rows; the five most used words in the file.

Therefore, I have used the .take(n) method to extract the required elements. However, an error is prompt when the result is attempted to be saved to a text file. I have tried saving the file a number of ways:

**Method 1**

```
val path = "Books/"+language+"/*"
    val textFile = sc.textFile(path)
        val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
            .map(word => (word,1))
            .reduceByKey(_+_)
    counts.collect()
    val sortedCounts = counts.map(p => (p._2, p._1)).sortByKey(false, 1)
    sortedCounts.collect()
    val check = sortedCounts.take(5)
    check.foreach(d => Files.write(Paths.get(language), (d._1 + " " + d._2 + "\n").getBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND))
```

*Error*

```
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/cloudera/Assessment 2/target/scala-2.10/classes ...
[error] /home/cloudera/Assessment 2/src/main/scala/task2.scala:27:22: not found: value Files
[error]         check.foreach(d => Files.write(Paths.get(language), (d._1).getBytes, StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND))     
[error]                            ^
[error] one error found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

**Method 2**

```
val path = "Books/"+language+"/*"
        val textFile = sc.textFile(path)
            val counts = textFile.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
                .map(word => (word,1))
                .reduceByKey(_+_)
        counts.collect()
        val sortedCounts = counts.map(p => (p._2, p._1)).sortByKey(false, 1)
        sortedCounts.collect()
        val check = sortedCounts.take(5)
        check.saveAsTextFile(language)

*Error*

    [info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/cloudera/Assessment 2/target/scala-2.10/classes ...
    [error] /home/cloudera/Assessment 2/src/main/scala/task2.scala:27:9: value saveAsTextFile is not a member of Array[(Int, String)]
    [error]         check.saveAsTextFile(language)
    [error]               ^
    [error] one error found
    [error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
    [error] Total time: 11 s, completed Nov 26, 2019 6:20:11 AM
```

**Important**
The file saves correctly before the .take() method is used. When **sortedCounts** is used with the saveAsTextFile(x) the entire map is saved. I do not want this as mentioned previously.

**How does one save an array[(string,int)] to a text file on hadoop via scala?**

Answer (score 0):

You can't save on Hadoop after you take/collect an RDD because it's a local Scala data-structure then, no longer within Spark

You need to use `sortedCounts.saveAsTextFile` and you should remove `counts.collect`